# Surface go 2 with surface pen - save sign metadata

Tags: c#, .net, digital-signature, surface

We use Wacom signpad, together with c# application for surface tablet. Wacom sends me image of sign and metadata (information for backcheck like pressure, speed, etc). This metadata we save in database with some security rules. It is for retrospective verification of sign.

The pressure level and resolution will be good on surface table too, so question is - can I get this metadata from surface without Wacom device? Has anyone experience with this?